# PoDoFo: Get ID of stream

Tags: pdf, podofo

Does anyone know how to get "ID" of stream in XObject? I need get ID as string how it is shown in the picture below - **/Im0**

[image]

In my C++ code I have exactly the XObject as PoDoFo::PdfReference but do not know how to get this ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has some issue so the solution is to get resources from Pdf Page as Dictionary and take XObject and get name of key, it's id of stream.